# SoundCloud Custom Player and YouTube Embed Player on https

Tags: https, youtube-api, soundcloud

I am using SoundCloud Custom Player on https site, everything works good but on chrome (html5 player) I get console alert that the player loads mp3 file from
http://ak-media.soundcloud.com...

This alert also occurs (on chrome yt-flash-player) while YT embed player (not iframe) loads video or crossdomain file from http

Is it possible to force those players to load source from https?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify what do you mean by SoundCloud Custom Player? Your own player which is built on top of Widget API or a standard (iframe-based) one?

I don't see any http request for widgets served via HTTPS.
Could you provide us with an example?

Comment: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player# this is the player which I use. I noticed that YT also has those alerts while visiting via https; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ujwod-vqyqA > console: The page at https://... displayed insecure content from http://...